# Is it okay to nest a dict.get() inside another or is this bad design?

Tags: python, dictionary, default

So, I am working on a code base where a dictionary contains some key information. At some point in the development process the name of one of the keys was changed, but the older key still exists in a lot of places. Lets call the keys `new` and `old` for reference.

In order to make it compatible with the older version, I am doing something like:

`dict_name.get(new_key,dict_name.get(old_key,None))`

Is this bad design or is it okay? Why/Why not?

### Example for clarification: (Based on input by @Alexander)

There are two dictionaries d1 and d2.

```
d1={k1:v1,old_key:some_value}
d2={k1:v1,new_key:some_value}
```

The function which I am designing right now could get either d1 or d2 like dictionary as an argument. My function should be able to pick up some_value, regardless of whether old_key or new_key is present.

Comment: This smells like bad design to me but it is difficult to judge without an example.

Comment: So, this is my exact scenario, there are two key names being used for the same objective because the name was changed at some point for other reasons (not related to coding). I can supply an example if you help me understand what kind of scenario/description would improve the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a reasonable approach.  The only downside is that it will perform the `get` for both keys, which will not affect performance in most situations.

My only notes are nitpicks:

- `dict` is a reserved word, so don't use it as a variable
- `None` is the default, so it can be dropped for `old_key`, e.g.:

```
info.get('a', info.get('b'))
```

---

In response to "Is there a way to prevent the double call?":  Yup, several reasonable ways exist =).

1. The one-liner would probably look like:

   `info['a'] if 'a' in info else info.get('b')`

   which starts to get difficult to read if your keys are longer.
2. A more verbose way would be to expand it out into full statements:

   ```
   val = None
   if 'a' in info:
       val = info['a']
   elif 'b' in info:
       val = info['b']
   ```
3. And finally a generic option (default after `*keys`) will only work with python 3):

   ```
   def multiget(info, *keys, default=None):
       ''' Try multiple keys in order, or default if not present '''
       for k in keys:
           if k in info:
               return info[k]
       return default
   ```

   which would let you resolve multiple invocations cleanly, e.g.:

   ```
   option_1 = multiget(info, 'a', 'b')
   option_2 = multiget(info, 'x', 'y', 'z', default=10)
   ```

If this is somehow a pandemic of multiple api versions or something (?) you could even go so far as wrapping `dict`, though it is likely to be overkill:

```
>>> class MultiGetDict(dict):
...   def multiget(self, *keys, default=None):
...       for k in keys:
...           if k in self:
...               return self[k]
...       return default
... 
>>> d = MultiGetDict({1: 2})
>>> d.multiget(1)
2
>>> d.multiget(0, 1)
2
>>> d.multiget(0, 2)
>>> d.multiget(0, 2, default=3)
3
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, dict is not the actual variable name. I'll edit that in the question. Is there a way to prevent the double call, if we are being nitpicky?

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get` is there for exactly this reason, so you can fall back on default values if the keys are not in there.

Having a double fallback is very much OK. For example:

```
d = {}
result = d.get('new_key',d.get('old_key', None))
```

This would mean that `result` is `None` in the worse case, but there is no error (which is the goal of `get` in the first place.

In other words, it will get the value of `new_key` as a first priority, `old_key` as the second priority, and `None` as a third.

Also worth noting that `get(key, None)` is the same as `get(key)` so you might want to shorten that line:

```
result = d.get('new_key', d.get('old_key'))
```

If you want to avoid calling `get` multiple times (for example, if you have to do more than 2 of those, it will be unreadable) you can do something like this:

```
priority = ('new_key', 'old_key', 'older_key', 'oldest_key')
for key in priority:
    result = d.get(key)
    if result is not None:
        break
```

And `result` becomes whatever is encountered first in that loop, or `None` otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample dictionary provided, I would argue that this is bad design...

Lets say your original dictionary is:

```
d1 = {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}
```

If I understand you correctly, you then 'update' one of the keys, e.g.:

```
d1 = {'k3': 1, 'k2': 2}
```

If you try to access via:

```
d1.get('k3', d1.get('k1'))  # 'k3' is new key, 'k1' is old key.
```

then the first lookup will always be present and the second lookup will never be used.

If you meant that the new dictionary would looks like:

```
d2 = {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 1}
```

then you are storing the 'same' data in two different locations in your dictionary, which will surely lead to trouble (similar to normalized data in a database). For example, if the value of 'k3' was updated to `3`, then the value of `k1` would need to be updated as well.

Given the dictionaries provided in your example:

```
d1={k1: v1, old_key: some_value}
d2={k1: v1, new_key: some_value}
```

I assume that `some_value` are intended to be equal in both, i.e. `d1[old_key] == d2[new_key]`.  If so, then you *could* use `d2.get(new_key, d1.get(old_key)`. However, it just seems like a mess.

- If `some_value` needs to be updated, for example, it must be updated in both dictionaries.
- You are wasting memory by storing the `some_value` twice.
- Your `new_key` in `d2` may accidentally clobber an existing key in `d1`.

I would recommend not changing the key names in the first place.

Comment: In this scenario, it would either be d1 or d2. (This is happening because d1 and d2 themselves are values of a dictionary that stores some information.). With that context, what would your comments on the design be? I'll update the question to make it more clear. Thanks for pointing that out!